# What’s the term for a website that allows you to use tabs to jump to different sections?

Tags: html, terminology

I’m using a [template from W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_templates_parallax&stacked=h). It allows you to jump to different pages when you click a tab.

What’s the term for that? I can’t find it, and I don’t know how the code works for it.

Comment: A navigation bar? Fragment identifier links? IMO, this is bad design, because these “tabs” look like menu links that navigate to a different page.

Comment: Yes those are the terms, thank you. Why is that bad? I think it works if you don't have a lot of content for a whole page

Comment: Because you would expect that these links open completely new pages, so perhaps you’d want to open them in new tabs, but in reality, they just scroll to a different portion of the page.

Comment: @Xufox Fair enough, I can see in the case of wanting to open in a new tab

Answer (score 1):

They are called *Single Page Sites* or less commonly *One Page Scrolling Sites*. The way of navigation that you are referring to and/or using is a common feature.

Reference: https://www.awwwards.com/websites/single-page/